# Django 1.4 Model formsets specify widget and change label

Tags: python, django

As it is said there - 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets
you could specify widgets for model's formsets only with Django 1.6. In our project we use 1.4, could anyone guide me how to make kind of backport for this?

Second part of my question is about changing labels:

```
class RegularAvailDateForm( ModelForm ):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RegularAvailDateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['active'].label = DOWS[self.instance.dow]

    class Meta:
            model = AvailabilitySchedule
            fields = ('active','dow', 'hour_start', 'hour_end')
            widgets = {
                    'active' :  CheckboxInput(),
                    'dow': HiddenInput(),
                    'hour_start': NumberInput(attrs={'min': '0', 'max': '23', 'step': '1'}),
                    'hour_end': NumberInput(attrs={'min': '1', 'max': '24', 'step': '1'}),
            }
```

where DOWS is just

```
DOWS = [_("Monday"),
    _("Tuesday"),
    _("Wednesday"),
    _("Thursday"),
    _("Friday"),
    _("Saturday"),
    _("Sunday"),
    ]
```

See - I change the labels in `__init__` method, so what is analog for model formsets? I think the answer is burried somewhere really deep in Django sources.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.4 you can [override the widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) of a `ModelForm`. The [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory) takes `ModelForm` as an argument.

I think you can acheive what you want by defining a model form with the required widgets, then use that model form when creating the formset. No backporting required.

```
class RegularAvailDateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AvailabilitySchedule
        fields = ('active','dow', 'hour_start', 'hour_end')
        widgets = {
            'active' :  CheckboxInput(),
            'dow': HiddenInput(),
            'hour_start': NumberInput(attrs={'min': '0', 'max': '23', 'step': '1'}),
            'hour_end': NumberInput(attrs={'min': '1', 'max': '24', 'step': '1'}),
        }

FormSet = modelformset_factory(AvailabilitySchedule, RegularAvailDateForm)
```

The same goes for the second part of your question. Don't dig deep into the formset code to try and set the label of a model form. Just pass `modelformset_factory` a model form that sets the correct labels in its `__init__` method.

Comment: Wow, I'll give it a try a bit later today, but where did you find that `The modelformset_factory takes ModelForm as an argument.`?

Comment: I've used this approach for a while, so I'm not sure where I first learned about it. It's not mentioned on the model formset docs that you linked to, but you can see the arguments if you click through to the docs for [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory).